# How can I install drywall that has warped from improper storage?

Tags: drywall

I have 90 sheets of drywall that I stored for a couple of months against a wall.  The warp is minimal but noticeable.  I tried hanging a sheet on a wall.  The nails pulled through in the middle where the drywall is bowed.
I have laid the 90 sheets flat on the ground on top of each other.
I assume that eventually the sheets will flatten out but I am anxious to get them hung.
Any thoughts?

Comment: Laid flat on bare ground (or even cold concrete floor). Not a good situation. You should lay down some wood to elevate the pile up off the ground. Let long enough it may straighten out. If you are in a hurry go purchase replacement drywall.

Answer (score 6):

First off, use screws - perhaps just my personal preference, but I don't have nearly the problem with them.

I assume you are laying the drywall horizontally (not vertically) and the bow along the long 8' (or 12') length (not the 4').

It might take a little longer, but you could screw a 2x4 along the face with the drywall in place to  force the board back against the studs until the all screws are in - One board centered in the middle should do with just securing it at 16" & 80" then pull the board and move on down the line.

Comment: I like the piece of 2x4 idea to pull the drywall flat while you screw the rest of it down. It appears the "vertical vs horizontal" debate will continue although fastening warped drywall might be easier to handle horizontally.

Answer (score -5):

Install them right, Vertically thank you very much! Then, you can lean on the bow to have no problem since you won't be getting caught short on a stud edge at the end. Drywall should be first screwed in the center anyway & for this specific reason, especially applicable to ceilings.

[Should Drywall be hung Horizontally or Vertically](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28484/should-drywall-be-hung-horizontally-or-vertically/82254#82254)

Comment: Typical. Ignorance only wants to stay ignorant.