# Drywall installation vertical or horizontal?

Tags: drywall

Should we install drywall sheets horizontally or vertically if we screw them on horizontal furs?
I know the question has been asked on this site in the past and I remember Iggy's answer (see below), but then I wonder if we should not install the panels horizontally on horizontal furs for reason #2 given by Iggy’s answer?

Iggy’s Answer:
[Should drywall be hung horizontally or vertically?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28484/should-drywall-be-hung-horizontally-or-vertically)

> Vertical Only, here’s the proof & truth!
>
> Why and How Horizontal’s Wrong (and why Vertical’s right)...don’t ruin
>   new from the start:
>
> 1 – Defective Seam ...
>
> ***2 – Unsupported Seam – Horizontal’s tapered edge is 90% unsupported, only 10% (instead of Vertical's 100%) contacts framing,
>   the seam will and does crack***. Light switch and countertop
>   electrical boxes within the seam equals more weakness and butt-joint
>   doubled, minimum, efforts.
>
> 3 – Structural Defect - ...

Comment: I agree, I think horizontal has less strength and put switches at a tape joint, you could place switches higher but then they would looks different. I also think verticle is better because there are no butt joints less shadows on longer walls. The pros that do horizontal do it that way because they say its faster.

Answer (score 1):

I've always been told horizontal, and it makes sense in that it makes taping easier and and reduces joints.

The main reason I've been told is that you want to avoid having a continuous seam from floor to ceiling. When the house settles, these are more likely to form a crack.

Also you don't want to place drywall seams at the corners of doors or windows. Previous owners (or whoever) put seams at the bottom of my windows and I've got nice cracks from the corner of the windows to the floor. As long as the horizontal seams are screwed very close to the edge at each student, I'm not sure how a horizontal crack could form.

Comment: I dissagree with verticle there are recessed joints top to bottom and but joints with no relief this makes shadows on anything longer than the sheet length then the switches set at 4' the normal height you are on a joint. Doors and windows have trim that hide the edges inside and outside corners have corner bead or tape. If a totally flat wall is specified for things like a big screen projector tv even the pros go verticle.

Comment: I have asked this question to drywallers. The answer that I was given is.... wood studs tend to warp with time so they install horizontal to reinforce the studs. In commercial, metal studs are used and so vertical boards make a more solid joint.

Answer (score 1):

In a kitchen, I tend to go horizontal, but with this method. I split the first piece in half length-wise and place the cut on the floor, leveling it. The next piece, full width, is set on top. The top piece, the other half of the first, and cut to fit, goes on last. Most of both tapered seams are hidden by cabinets and all I have to finish carefully are the screw holes, but the only part that shows is that above the counter top. Switches aren’t at a seam. Very quick. Taught to me by an old mud master.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the studs are strapped horizontally. The reason you apply horizontal is to bridge the studs, so there is never a joint floor to ceiling reducing the deflective resistance of the single stud behind the joint, and the un beveled shorter and weaker joint is fully supported. The advantage to floor to ceiling application is the joints are all beveled and can be made tighter. Not strength! There’s a reason structural engineers haven’t changed this in a hundred years

Comment: I'm sure there's some good info in here, but this is a confusing read. Please [edit] your answer to clarify: "Only if the studs are strapped horizontally" - I believe that's actually the premise of the question. "reducing the deflective resistance of the single stud" - clarification? "joints are all beveled and can be made tighter" - isn't there a bevel no matter which way the board is installed? Can't that be made tight either way? What is it that hasn't changed in 100 years?

Comment: Please don't add signatures to your posts here. See [answer] and take the [tour].